# Damerau-Levenshtein Distance for MySQL

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь реализовать на сайте "нечеткий" поиск по формуле Дамерау-Левенштейна.

Взял PHP исходники с гитхаба.

Получаю ошибку "Mysql query error: (1305) FUNCTION dbname.DAMLEVLIM does not exist (400)".

Где взять эту функцию DAMLEVLIM?

Answer (score 0):

#### Вот что сработало у меня (Centos 7, VMBitrix):

1. Скачал репозиторий отсюда: https://github.com/ifsnop/damlev
2. Разархивировал и залил на сервер в папку /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/damlev-master (без разницы какая папка)
3. В файле Makefile изменил "**-L/usr/lib/mysql \**" на "**-L/usr/lib64/mysql \**" (Папку с плагинами можно найти так: **SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "plugin_dir";**)
4. Запустил **make** в папке, куда закачал репозиторий. В папке **lib** появился файл **mysqldamlevlim.so**
5. Закинул файл **mysqldamlevlim.so** в папку с плагинами MySQL (/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin)
6. Запустил **mysql** и выполнил там следующие комманды:

```
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS damlevlim;
    CREATE FUNCTION damlevlim RETURNS INT SONAME 'mysqldamlevlim.so';
    SELECT * FROM mysql.func;
```

7. В ответе убедился, что библиотека установилась:

[image: damlevlim installed successfuly]

Answer (score -1):

Нужно перекомпилировать MySQL для поддержки этой функции. Вот [инструкция](https://samjlevy.com/mysql-levenshtein/). Вот ссылка на [github](https://github.com/ifsnop/damlev) с описанием проблем.

Comment: Какой путь выбрать: Compiling on Linux или Installing UDF as MySQL plugin on Linux (используется Linux)?

Comment: "gcc: error: levenshtein.cc: Нет такого файла или каталога"

Comment: @Сергей я же не вижу, что вы делаете. Как вам удобно так и настраивайте.

Comment: к сожалению, инструкция нерабочая

Comment: Это официальный гайд от разработчика.

Comment: Я попробовал на последнем Debian, компилируется.

Comment: не распишете по шагам?

Comment: @Сергей я делал по приведенной инструкции.

Comment: можно с вами пообщаться в чате?

Comment: В каком чате? Здесь есть чат?